# Lack of randomness in numpy.random

Tags: python, numpy

Although the input data I'm working is randomly generated, when I used matplotlib to graph it, I got only a few different distinct points! I used the expression

```
[[numpy.random.randint(0,20) + numpy.random.random() for i in xrange(100)] for j in xrange(2)]
```

to generate the data I expected something that would resemble a surface. Also, I did not add any randomness to the output, as I wanted to ensure that the fit worked before I did.

The outputs are also suspicious, as they should have been generated with the equation

```
z = 112x/2 + 2^.15y + 109
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are some views of the plot:

[image: figure]
  [image: figure]
  [image: figure]

Comment: you should try to update the pictures...

Comment: What is this equation for? Is it needed to understand the actual question?

Comment: Why do you not use something like `20*numpy.random.random()` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The code looks better now, but the same problem still persists. I am confused as to why there are multiple z coordinates for every (x,y) pair, and I believe that it is linked to the strangeness of the x,y distribution.

Comment: Can you paste the matplotlib code? You can do something like `>>> np.bincount(np.digitize(np.random.rand(50000)*5,np.arange(1,5)))
array([ 9946,  9867, 10155, 10127,  9905])` to show the even distribution of numpy's rand function.

Comment: I just noticed that the code is seeded with a SEED = randint(0,1000000000) expression. Would this have an effect on the randomness? Looking through the list of values, there are quite a few repetitions. Every time I generate the list, there is at least one duplicate of each number.

Comment: Please generate your random numbers as `np.random.rand(2,100)*20`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with my numpy. It would be good if you shared your code, as the error is probably there, since the following works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.array([[np.random.randint(0,20) + np.random.random()
                  for i in xrange(100)] for j in xrange(2)])
z = 112*x/2 + 2**.15*y + 109

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

As other have noted, the right way of generating your numbers would be:

```
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 20
```

or even

```
x, y = np.random.randint(20, size=(2, 100)) + np.random.rand(2, 100)
```

but that has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for that. The values do pass through a database before being interpreted, so I'll check there.

Comment: I put the plot generation code in the database generator script, and in the database wrapper, and it looks completely different, now I know where to truly look

Comment: After a good deal of fiddling with the database tools, here it is: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zIWl6.png Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This distribution looks OK to me.  It doesn't look like a surface because you're not generating real numbers, just integers, which is why those "bars" are being formed.

Comment: I changed the code to numpy.random.random()*20, and I still get the same bars.

Comment: It's because what you appear to be doing is generating 20 random numbers and then assigning them to one random value.  Basically you're generating a list like [1.2, 1.5, 18.2, etc] and assigning that to one Y value instead of N Y values so all of those form a bar.